# Добавление фото в google контакты через api

Tags: python, google-контакты

Я пытаюсь добавить фото с компьютера к контактам в google

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
import os
import re
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import GTokenRefresh


def get_contacts():
    """
    Получает список контактов из Google Contacts.

    Returns:
        List[dict]: Список контактов.
    """
    # Create an OAuth2Session for authentication
    client_id = os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
    client_secret = os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    access_token = os.environ["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"]

    oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, token={"access_token": access_token})

    # Make the API request
    try:
        # Используйте правильный URL для получения контактов
        response = oauth.get(
            "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=names"
        )
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception if the request is not successful
        contacts = response.json().get("connections", [])
        print(f"Successfully fetched {len(contacts)} contacts.")
        return contacts
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(f"Error fetching contacts: {e}")
        return []


def add_photo(contact, photo_path):
    # Получаем имя контакта.
    name = contact.get("names", [{}])[0].get("displayName", "")

    if not name:
        print("No display name found for the contact.")
        return

    # Загружаем фото на сервер Google Contacts.
    with open(photo_path, "rb") as photo_file:
        photo_data = photo_file.read()

    response = requests.post(
        f"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/{contact['resourceName']}/photos",
        data=photo_data,
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {os.environ['GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN']}",
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
        },
    )

    # Проверяем успешность запроса на загрузку фото
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(
            f"Error uploading photo for {name}: {response.status_code} - {response.text}"
        )
        return

    print(f"Successfully uploaded photo for {name}")


def main():
    # Получаем список контактов.
    contacts = get_contacts()
    print(contacts)
    # Путь к папке с фотографиями на компьютере
    photo_directory = "C:\\Photo"

    # Формируем список файлов фото.
    photo_files = os.listdir(photo_directory)
    photo_files = [
        os.path.join(photo_directory, file)
        for file in photo_files
        if re.match(r"[А-Яа-я]+, [А-Яа-я]+, [А-Яа-я]+.jpg", file)
    ]

    # Сопоставляем контакты и фото.
    for contact in contacts:
        for photo in photo_files:
            contact_name = contact.get("names", [{}])[0].get("displayName", "")
            photo_name = os.path.basename(photo).split(".jpg")[0]
            if contact_name == photo_name:
                add_photo(contact, photo)
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_access_token, client_secret, client_id = GTokenRefresh.main()
    os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"] = str(client_id)
    os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"] = str(client_secret)
    os.environ["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"] = str(new_access_token)
    print(os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"])
    print(os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"])
    main()
```

Консоль:

```
    Успешно обновленный токен: ya29.a0AfB_by******
*****.apps.googleusercontent.com
    GOCSPX-*****
    Successfully fetched 100 contacts.
    [{'resourceName': 'people/c114622133179475310', 'etag': '%EgUBAi43PRoEAQIFByIMQ0Y3MnVGM0J5eUU9', 'names': [{'metadata': {'primary': True, 'source': {'type': 'CONTACT', 'id': '19738390b8f656e'}}, итд...
```

Но на самом деле код ничего не делает =/ направьте пожалуйста - в какую сторону идти?

Answer (score 0):

Доделал, не совсем оптимально, нужно переделать что бы он сливал список контактов один раз, а не запрашивал для каждого нового контакта, но работает, может кому будет полезен:

```
import GTokenRefresh
import os
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import requests
import base64
import json


def extract_name_from_image(image_path):
    print(f"Извлечение Фамилии, Имени и Отчества из имени файла: {image_path}")
    filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
    filename_without_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    name_parts = filename_without_extension.split()
    if len(name_parts) >= 3:
        last_name, first_name, middle_name = name_parts[:3]
        print(f"Фамилия: {last_name}, Имя: {first_name}, Отчество: {middle_name}")
        return last_name, first_name, middle_name
    else:
        print("Недостаточно частей в имени файла.")
        return None


def read_contacts_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as contact_file:
        contacts = [json.loads(line.strip()) for line in contact_file.readlines()]
    return contacts


def assign_images_to_contacts(image_folder, contacts):
    print("Назначение изображений контактам из файла...")
    for contact in contacts:
        contact_names = contact.get("names", [])
        if contact_names:
            contact_name = contact_names[0]
            contact_last_name = contact_name.get("familyName", "")
            contact_first_name = contact_name.get("givenName", "")
            contact_middle_name = contact_name.get("middleName", "")
            contact_full_name = (
                f"{contact_last_name}, {contact_first_name}, {contact_middle_name}"
            )
            filename = (
                f"{contact_last_name} {contact_first_name} {contact_middle_name}.jpg"
            )
            image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, filename)

            if os.path.exists(image_path):
                assign_image_to_contact(image_path, contact)
            else:
                print(f"Изображение для {contact_full_name} не найдено.")
    print("Назначение изображений завершено.")


def get_contacts_and_save_to_file(client_id, client_secret, access_token):
    print("Запрос списка контактов...")
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, token={"access_token": access_token})
    all_contacts = []

    try:
        page_token = None
        while True:
            params = {
                "personFields": "names,emailAddresses",
                "pageSize": 1000,
            }
            if page_token:
                params["pageToken"] = page_token

            response = oauth.get(
                "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections", params=params
            )
            response.raise_for_status()
            connections = response.json().get("connections", [])
            all_contacts.extend(connections)

            page_token = response.json().get("nextPageToken")
            if not page_token:
                break

        with open("mycontacts.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as contact_file:
            for contact in all_contacts:
                contact_file.write(json.dumps(contact) + "\n")

        total_contacts = len(all_contacts)
        print(
            f"Список контактов сохранен в файл 'mycontacts.txt'. Общее количество контактов: {total_contacts}"
        )
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при получении списка контактов: {e}")


def assign_image_to_contact(image_path, contact):
    if not contact:
        print("Контакт не найден.")
        return

    contact_names = contact.get("names", [])
    if contact_names:
        contact_name = contact_names[0]
        contact_last_name = contact_name.get("familyName", "")
        contact_first_name = contact_name.get("givenName", "")
        contact_middle_name = contact_name.get("middleName", "")
        contact_full_name = (
            f"{contact_last_name}, {contact_first_name}, {contact_middle_name}"
        )

        print(f"Назначение изображения профиля для контакта: {contact_full_name}")

        with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
            image_bytes = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode("utf-8")

        image_resource = {"photoBytes": image_bytes}
        image_update_url = f"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{contact['resourceName']}:updateContactPhoto"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {os.environ['GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN']}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }

        try:
            response = requests.patch(
                image_update_url, json=image_resource, headers=headers
            )
            response.raise_for_status()
            print("Изображение профиля успешно назначено.")
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            print(f"Ошибка при назначении изображения: {e}")


def main():
    image_folder = "C:/test"
    client_id = os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
    client_secret = os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    access_token = os.environ["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"]

    get_contacts_and_save_to_file(client_id, client_secret, access_token)
    contacts = read_contacts_from_file("mycontacts.txt")
    assign_images_to_contacts(image_folder, contacts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_access_token, client_secret, client_id = GTokenRefresh.main()
    os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"] = str(client_id)
    os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"] = str(client_secret)
    os.environ["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"] = str(new_access_token)
    main()
```